# Сообщение при наведении на блок

Tags: jquery

Всем привет.

Хочу сделать изменение класса у элемента при наведении на него.

Сейчас у меня так:

```
$(".owner-comment").hover( function() {
    //$(this).addClass('hover', e.type === 'mouseenter');
    alert('asdsadsd2');
});
```

При первой загрузке страницы все нормально работает и показывает alert.

При клике на кнопку загружаются новые элементы. Точно такая же разметка, отличается только контент.
Загрузка через .load

```
$(document).on('click','.mrr a',function(){
      var rtype = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0];
      var rabout = $("#usidvl #curuser").val();
      $(".mrr .rwinpval").val(rtype);
      $(".rwloady").load('/include/pages/reviews/api.php?about='+rabout+'&type='+rtype+'&getrv=yes&myrv=yes', function (){ thisPageNum = 2; } );
      return false;  
});
```

После клика на элемент ".mrr a", алерт уже не появляется. 
Подскажите как подправить чтобы алерт показывался и после .load

Comment: Попробуйте переписать так:  

    $(".owner-comment").on("hover", function() {
        //$(this).addClass('hover', e.type === 'mouseenter');
        alert('asdsadsd2');
    });

Comment: @ReinRaus не сработало

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).on('hover','.owner-comment', function() {
    //$(this).addClass('hover', e.type === 'mouseenter');
    alert('asdsadsd2');
});
```

**UPDATE:**

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.owner-comment',  function(){
         $(this).addClass('hover');
        alert('asdsadsd2');
}).on('mouseleave', '.owner-comment', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```

Comment: Получилось! Спасибо.

Comment: @Genson можете еще подсказать метод для удаления класса если убрал курсор с блока?

Comment: @Genson нашел сам уже

Comment: $(document).on('mouseover','.owner-comment', function() { 
  $(this).addClass('cfse_a');
 });
 $(document).on('mouseout','.owner-comment', function() { 
  $(this).removeClass('cfse_a');
 });

Comment: обновил ответ